# diagonalizable matrices using eigenvectors

Tags: linear-algebra, diagonalization

I'm wondering how one can generally go about to diagonalize a linear transformation, especially using a basis consisting of eigenvectors.

For example, this problem:

Let $T: \mathbb{R}^3 → \mathbb{R}^3$ be the linear operator which is represented in the standard ordered basis by the matrix

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
    -9 & 4 & 4 \\
    -8 & 3 & 4 \\
    -16 & 8 & 7
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Prove that $T$ is diagonalizable by exhibiting a basis for $\mathbb{R}^3$ consisting of eigenvectors for $T$.

Comment: I'm not sure what your question is, exactly: are you stuck on how to write down the diagonalization once you've computed the eigenvalues and eigenvectors? Or are you stuck on computing the eigenvalues and eigenvectors?

Comment: I'm not sure neither. What does this problem mean by asking to diagonalize "by exhibiting a basis for $\mathbb{R}^3$ consisting of eigenvectors for T"?

Comment: Can you find the eigenvectors of T? If there are three independent ones, then T is diagonalizable, because when it acts on an eigenvector it just multiplies it by a constant; there is no mixing in from the other eigenvectors. But if there are three independent eigenvectors, they form a basis. So all you have to do is find them and show they are linearly independent.